# How to check Dinghy logs?

Tags: spinnaker, dinghy

I followed the instructions to install Dinghy on my Spinnaker installation using https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker/install_dinghy. But I don't see my pipelines being updated.

I see the spin-clouddriver showing the webhooks are being received but nothing else.

How do I check the logs for Dinghy so I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run `hal deploy apply` and enable the Github service. Then I started seeing updates to my Spinnaker pipelines.